# What is the maximum number of "root subtrees" that a tree can have?

Tags: trees

Let $T=(V,E)$ be a directed rooted tree with root $r \in V$. A *root subtree*$^1$ of $T$ is a directed rooted tree $T'=(V',E')$ that fulfills the following conditions:

- $T'$ is a subgraph of $T$,
- $r \in V'$
- for each node $v \in V'$, either all children of $v$ in $T$ are also in $V'$, or none of them is.

For example, let

$T=$[image] $T'=$[image] $T''=$[image] $T'''=$[image] .

Then both $T'$ and $T''$ are root subtrees of $T$, but $T'''$ isn't.

Now my question is this: **How can the maximum number of root subgraphs of a tree T be expressed as a function of its size $s$?**

More formally, I'm looking for a closed-form expression for the function $f$ s.t. $f(s) = \max\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \text{there is a tree $T$ with size $s$ s.t. $T$ has $n$ root subtrees } \}$. I'm assuming $f = \mathcal{O}(2^s)$, but I'm interested in the exact number.

**Edit:** If this helps, I think that the first values of $f$ are:

- $f(s) = s$, $1 \leq s \leq 5$
- $f(6) = 7$
- $f(7) = 9$

If I am correct, then examples for trees of size $1, \ldots, 7$ that have the maximum number of root subtrees are:

[image]

$^1$ I made that name up as I don't know whether there already is a name for this concept.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $f(s)=2^{s-1}$.

Comment: Unless you're talking about binary trees. That wasn't specified but your examples are.

Comment: I'm not talking about binary trees. I don't think that $f(s) = 2^{s-1}$ is the correct solution. I've added the first few values of $f$ to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of rooted subtrees of a tree is the product of the numbers of rooted subtrees of the root's children plus one. [Here's code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/342c4f5437036ed2ed83777eb06d4dcd) that recursively computes $f(s)$. The result is [OEIS sequence A007601](https://oeis.org/A007601), which is a shifted version of [OEIS sequence A000792](https://oeis.org/A000792). Apparently for $s\ge3$ we have

$$
f(s)=1+\left(\left\{\frac s3\right\}+\frac23\right)3^{\left\lfloor\frac s3\right\rfloor}\;,
$$

where $\{x\}$ denotes $\lfloor x\rfloor-x$, the fractional part of $x$.

Note that you got $f(7)$ wrong; $f(7)=10$, since it's better to have two children with $3$ nodes each than three children with $2$ nodes each.